# inappropriate output while creating a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to stream the data from  kafka topic using scala application.I'm able to get the data from the topic, but how to create a data frame out of it?

Here is the data(in string,string format)

```
{
  "action": "AppEvent",
  "tenantid": 298,
  "lat": 0.0,
  "lon": 0.0,
  "memberid": 16390,
  "event_name": "CATEGORY_CLICK",
  "productUpccd": 0,
  "device_type": "iPhone",
  "device_os_ver": "10.1",
  "item_name": "CHICKEN"
}
```

I tried few ways to do it, but  it is not yielding satisfactory results.

```
 +--------------------+ |                  _1|
 +--------------------+ |{"action":"AppEve...| |{"action":"AppEve...| |{"action":"AppEve...| |{"action":"AppEve...| |{"action":"AppEve...|
 |{"action":"AppEve...| |{"action":"AppEve...| |{"action":"AppEve...|
 |{"action":"AppEve...| |{"action":"AppEve...|
```

Can anyone tell How to do the mapping so that each field goes in to a seperate column like a table. the data is in avro format.

here is the code which is getting the data from the topic.

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
val kafkaConf = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> "####",
     "zookeeper.connect" -> "########",
     "group.id" -> "KafkaConsumer",
     "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "1000000")
val topicMaps = Map("fishbowl" -> 1)
val messages  = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String,DefaultDecoder, DefaultDecoder](ssc, kafkaConf, topicMaps, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER).map(_._2)
```

please guide me how to use foreachRDD func and map() to create a proper data frame

Comment: Did you try to do a search? [spark-streaming + dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bspark-streaming%5D+dataframe)

Comment: it is not helpful, as im new to scala.I couldnt figure it out how to convert a avro[String,String] to dataframe  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237929/value-toint-is-not-a-member-of-object

Comment: Here is my answer Thanks Maasg found the answer

Answer (score 2):

To create a dataframe out of an rdd irrespective of its case class schema.
Use this below logic

```
stream.foreachRDD(
  rdd => {
     val dataFrame = sqlContext.read.json(rdd.map(_._2)) 
dataFrame.show()
        })
```

**Here stream is an rdd created from kafkaUtils.createStream()**

Comment: Well done. Regarding  the comment "irrespective of its format or case class schema"  that's not exactly correct => This works only for JSON-formatted records.

Comment: @maasg thanks sir, edited my comment. As i worked it out with avro(Still its schema is in json)